# Logical disjunction and English Language

Tags: meaning, word-usage, expressions, meaning-in-context, terminology

In Logic Or signals a Logical disjuction it means an inclusive OR.

I get into trouble when saying OR and mean inclusive OR.

Is the person Black or Male?

I usually get this considered a "wrong" question.

How can I make it explicit that I mean inclusive OR, in a natural and formal way?

And/or does not seem formal or natural.

Comment: In contemporary English you can say "and/or".

Comment: @ThePhoton How formal and natural is it?

Comment: It's very common in writing, but not particularly natural in speech. If you want a more natural idiom for speech, you have to say "black or male or both".

Comment: @ThePhoton Will you expect any PhD thesis or Post-PhD researches, Habilitation or Fellowship thesis in Oxford University in the departments of Medicine, English or Law to contain and/or unless it was a Thesis studying precisely And/Or's usage in the English language or Logical disjunction? Language in those texts would be both formal and natural. Anything else is excluded for being mostly informal.

Comment: I've never written a thesis at Oxford. My university had a style guide for theses to answer questions like this. If yous doesn't, ask your advisor

Comment: Another approach - I have no idea whether it would be useful in your situation - is to define expressions like 'Black or Male' as a category, or just present them as a category - if you say for example *in this study, how many respondents were black or male?*, the *or* will be understood inclusively, i.e. the sentence will be unpacked as *how many respondents were (black or male)*, whereas the one in your question would be unpacked *is this person black or [is this person] male*. It's this parallel structure that makes us interpret the possibilities as mutually exclusive.

Comment: In normal speech, *or* can be treated either inclusively or exclusively. It depends on context and the interpretation of the listener. I've always considered it to be inclusive, and only used explicit terminology when I've wanted to express an exclusive *or*. But the given answer is correct in terms of explicit language to use for an implicit *or*. (I personally despise the use of *and/or*, although I acknowledge that many have no problem with it.)

Comment: As an alternative to saying "and/or" you could use "black or male or both."

Comment: As a native English speaker I have no idea what your inclusive OR is. If you explain what you mean you will presumably answer your question.

Comment: @David Is the capitalisation a problem? https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/or NOUN
1"OR" A logical operation which gives the value one if at least one operand has the value one, and otherwise gives a value of zero. https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/inclusive_or https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-an-inclusive-or-and-an-exclusive-or

Comment: No, nothing to do with caps. The whole terminology is not one I have encountered. If it is that represented in bureaucratic documents by and/or, I suggest you write an example in a sentence and then explain why that will not do.

Comment: @George That is an absolutely insane definition of ‘formal’ and ‘informal’. PhD theses from Cambridge or from the Department of Biochemistry or Archaelogy at Oxford, legal texts, official letters from Buckingham Palace – all those would by your definition be considered informal texts, which they most certainly are not, by any stretch of the imagination. (In a formal context, you’d also have to get the name of the University of Oxford right, as well as its Radcliffe Department of Medicine, Faculty of English Language and Literature, and Faculty of Law.)

Comment: "I usually get this considered a "wrong" question." _By whom?_ There needs to be more context given. After "We are eliminating certain classes of people from our research...." the follow-on question "Is the person you're mentioning black or male?" would, outside schools of logic, be considered acceptable and answers "Black **and** male / Both," "Black and female,"  "Non-black but male," and "Non-black and female / Neither" (and "I don't know" etc) would be acceptable. But, after "I met someone interesting yesterday; you guess what they're like" a two-point question is unreasonable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you wish to communicate so that what is understood by the people to whom you wish to communicate is what you mean, then I urge you never to think of relying on formal logic, however unambiguous it might seem to you.

So the problem with "Is he black or male?" is not just ambiguity in the ears of the listeners (because most listeners will not be aware of the different types of 'or') but is that the question is bizarre. You have to spell out what you mean.

I share Jason Bassford's hatred of 'and/or' on stylistic grounds, but there is another objection: a question with 'and/or' in it is highly likely to be perceived as confusing, particularly in speech.  Complicated logical questions do need to be posed clearly, and that means with repetition and redundancy.

Answer (score 1):

The specifity of "or" is conditional on context. *new or old* cannot be inclusive. *broken or otherwise dysfunctional* is basically just *dysfunctional*. *thirsty or hungry* is not mutually exclusive, though a little redundant.

I am not sure what the rejection of *black or male* implies about racial hyper-sensitivity. The answer *Both!* would be well acceptable. And there is no need to alter the question,  if the addition *[...] or both?* is chiefly implied (this is achieved through intonation, which is missing in writing, but several alternatives would be available).

Comment: I have a problem reading your answer.

Answer (score 0):

In contemporary English, "and/or" is becoming fairly common, in both writing and speech.

An alternative that might come across more naturally in some contexts is to ask something like "Is the person black or male or both?" There's still an inherent ambiguity about whether you want a yes/no answer, or if you want an answer from the three alternatives offered. However if you want a yes/no answer and the other person answers with "both", you can still interpret that as a yes.