# What is the difference in nuance of amiable and affable?

Tags: meaning, etymology, differences, synonyms, semantics

Both come from Latin.

The noun amicus(friend) from amo(I love)

The verb affor(to address) from ad + for(to speak to)

I am pretty sure etymologically amiable should be much more warm, pleasant and friendly. Amiable should be closer to friendly. While Affable should be closer to easy to talk with.

Nonetheless a Semantic change/drift might have occured.

**What is the difference in nuance of amiable and affable?**

A possible answer to my question could be given by [Jim's](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/17956/jim) [comment](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/513093/what-is-the-difference-in-nuance-of-amiable-and-affable?noredirect=1#comment1243822_513093).

If so I would need a confirmation of whether amiability(amiableness) is the active/intent desire to please while affability(affableness) is the passive condition of actually pleasing regardless of any will to do so.

Comment: For me, amiable is more about willingness to do whatever makes others happy while affable is to do with being likable.

Comment: Checking the meaning of words from their derivation rather than a dictionary is the [etymological fallacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Etymological_fallacy).

Comment: @Jim A reductionist definition could be posible but for that we need to be able to associate and commutate the method to define words(If a is characterized by b and we define only b or If b is a quality of a and we define only a we should understand the same things for a and b regardless of the method we choose). Pluraritas no est ponenda sine necessitas. Someone amiable/affable is one who is characterized by amiability/affability(amiableness/affableness). Amiability is the active/intent desire to please while Affability is the passive condition of pleasing?

Comment: George, I really hope you're not treating English (or any other generally used language) as mathematically rigorous. It won't work; the reasons why might make a good question for Linguistics.SE

Comment: @TimLymington I am looking deeper and further at their etymology to discover any eventual nuances. A dictionary only gives someone the essential rules, some tools, a very gross guideline on semantics. It is not that I am looking only at their etymology. The dictionary gave me very similar definitions. As a learner of English as a foreign language I really prefer Oxford and Cambridge to Merriam Webster. They are easier to read and more comprehensive. But all 3 are vague on the nuances.

Comment: @TimLymington But I have no problem being pedantic at the expense of idiomaticity. I just cannot knowingly deviate from Formal logic. Set Theory, Rules of Induction, etc are all deeply ingrained into myself. I can only understand something if I understand its fundaments. I can do mistakes on Logic and I am deeply saddened by this fact.

Comment: @TimLymington Just an example. https://english.stackexchange.com/a/506716/356033

Comment: At present this question doesn't meet ELU standards (sorry); I encourage you to visit chat, or maybe to check the help site for what is expected.

Comment: @TimLymington If you are earnestly sorry and would be as kind to explain please do so. What and Why. Please be clear on the ELU standards(which are they) and why(how) my question does not meet the standards. I would obviously not ask a question that I know it infringes ELU standards; either I do not know these standards, cannot understand them( ignorance of rules is not pardoned but vague/ambiguous rules are forbidden by ethics) or I do not understand how my question infringes said clear rules. Please explain the standards and how(why) my question infringes them!

Answer (score 2):

I don't know where you got the etymology from but [Etymoline](https://www.etymonline.com/word/affable) says

> of persons, "***open to conversation or approach***," late 15c., from Old French ***affable*** "benign, approachable" (14c.), from Latin ***affabilis*** "approachable, courteous, kind, friendly," ***literally "who can be (easily) spoken to***," from ***affari*** "*to speak to*," from ***ad*** "*to*", from PIE root *bha- (2) "to speak, tell, say".

In fact, the meaning I have emphasised was preserved in the modern use of the word:

[Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/affable) defines ***affable*** as meaning

> friendly and ***easy to talk to***: *She was quite affable at the meeting.*

And [AHD](https://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=affable) says

> ***Easy and pleasant to speak to***; approachable.

(The same reference to speech is present in ***ineffable*** - which cannot be spoken, indescribable)

***Amiable*** is [more commonly](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=amiable%2Caffable%2C%20amicable&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Camiable%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Caffable%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Camicable%3B%2Cc0) used than than its other variant, ***amicable*** and than ***affable***. [Etymoline](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=amiable) says about it:

> late 14c., "kindly, friendly," also "***worthy of love or
> admiration***," from Old French amiable "pleasant, kind; ***worthy to
> be loved***" (12c.), from Late Latin amicabilis "friendly," from Latin
> amicus "friend, loved one," noun use of an adjective, "friendly,
> loving," from amare "to love".
>
> The form and sense were confused in Old French with ***amable***
> "lovable" (from Latin amare "to love"), and by 16c. the English word
> also had a secondary sense of "***exciting love or delight***,"
> especially by having an agreeable temper and a kind heart. *The word
> was subsequently reborrowed by English in Latin form without the sense
> contamination* as ***amicable***.

[Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/amiable) defines it as

> pleasant and friendly

and [AHD](https://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=amiable) as

> 1. Friendly and agreeable in disposition; good-natured and likable.
> 2. Cordial; sociable; congenial: an amiable gathering.

There is definitely an overlap between the two in use, they can both mean *pleasant and friendly*, but these definitions show ***amiable*** to describe someone or something that is ***likable*** (easy to like), whereas ***affable*** someone or something that is  ***approachable*** (easy to approach or talk to, therefore welcoming).

Having said all that, here is what a native speaker said about this issue on a [forum](https://hinative.com/en-US/questions/46642)

> ***Affable***: I'd use this to describe someone who gets on well with almost anybody. An affable person would most likely be considered kind
> and generous by people around them. For me it also carries the nuance
> that this person may be outgoing and extroverted as opposed to
> reserved and introverted.
>
> ***Amiable***: This word has a kind of flexible nature to it, like pliable or malleable. Maybe it's for this reason that I think of an
> amiable person as being someone who gets on well with others because
> they are able to look past their faults. *There is a very slight
> nuance that **an amiable person may be taken advantage of** because
> they try their best to be amiable, as in they try to always be
> accommodating to others. ***An affable person would be more likely to
> speak their mind*** when they think something is off, whereas an
> amiable person might stay quiet and just go along with whatever it
> is.*